# Given diagonal vertices of a square, how to i find all the other two vertices?? None of the sides are paralled to the x/y axis

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry, coordinate-systems, cartesian-coordinates

Example: I have two points (2,6) and (8,4) which are the opposite vertices of a square. How do i find the coordinates of the other two vertices?

Answer (score 2):

middle point

```
m.x = (a.x + b.x) / 2
m.y = (a.y + b.y) / 2
```

perpendicular vector

```
p.x = (a.y - b.y) / 2
p.y = (b.x - a.x) / 2
```

vertices (plus or minus for vertex choice)

```
v.x = m.x +/- p.x
v.y = m.y +/- p.y
```